# RJDBC and orientdb - have connection and see tables but cannot fetch the content

Tags: orientdb, rjdbc

I use the following code to connect orientDB using RJDBC

```
library(RJDBC)
drv <- JDBC("com.orientechnologies.orient.jdbc.OrientJdbcDriver","/Users/sofiaapreleva/programs/orien    tdb-jdbc-1.7-all.jar", "`")
conn <- dbConnect(drv, "jdbc:orient:local:GratefulDeadConcerts",'admin','admin')
res<-dbGetQuery(conn, "select * from V")
```

I can see tables:

```
dbListTables(conn)
[1] "followed_by" "V"           "ORIDs"       "OUser"       "OFunction"   "OTriggered"   "ORestricted" "E"          
[9] "OIdentity"   "ORole"       "OSchedule"
```

But i am getting the error trying to get query command:

```
> res<-dbGetQuery(conn, "select * from V")
Error in .valueClassTest(standardGeneric("fetch"), "data.frame", "fetch") : 
invalid value from generic function ‘fetch’, class “NULL”, expected “data.frame”
```

any suggestions on what I might do wrong..

Comment: If somebody uses successfully RJDBC to work with orientDB? very little of information on the web...

Comment: I think the main problem is double authentication - one pair is in config file, second is in admin/adminand so on. RJDBC provides only one place where to put user/password pair. I tried to create arrays and so on - nothing worked. Finally was able to find easy solution for connection with orientDB - but not from R, from python - pyorient module. Easy to use, worked and has very nice errors description.